# Update trigger when row doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have two tables
Orderitems:

```
"ORDER_ITEMS_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ORDER_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ITEM_CODE_ORDERS" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ORDER_QUANTITY" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ORDER_UNIT" VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"UNIT_PRICE" NUMBER(38,5), 
"ORDERED_IN" VARCHAR2(6), 
"OR_QUANTITY_TON" NUMBER(38,5),
"Warehouse_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE
```

the other table is Inventory:

```
"INVENTORY_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ITEM_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"WAREHOUSE_CODE" VARCHAR2(20),  
"IN_Q_TON" NUMBER(38,5), 
"OR_Q_TON" NUMBER(38,5)
```

I created a trigger to calculate "OR_QUANTITY_TON" = Sum ("OR_QN_TON")

```
create or replace trigger sum_Or_IT
after insert or update or delete on orderitems
begin
    update INVENTORY set OR_Q_TON = (
        select sum(or_quantity_ton) from orderitems 
        where
        orderitems.item_code_orders = INVENTORY.item_code
        and
        warehouse_code = '1');
end;
```

this is an inventory table and the column OR_Q_TON is the sum of the ordered quantity for every item,, but if an item doesn't exist in the orders ,, I want the order quantity to be zero. 
I want to make an exception if the "item_code_orders" doesn't exist in the table "Orderitems" then the OR_Q_TON = 0

I tried this but it didn't work I got (-) not (0)

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    update INVENTORY set OR_Q_TON = 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trigger should be

```
create or replace trigger sum_Or_IT
after insert or update or delete  on orderitems
begin
    update INVENTORY set OR_Q_TON = (
        select coalesce(sum(or_quantity_ton),0) from orderitems 
        where
        orderitems.item_code_orders = INVENTORY.item_code
        and
        warehouse_code = '1')        
end;
```

the problem solved by using coalesce function instead of the exception

Answer (score 0):

its is not an exception ,  AND oracle will not raise excpetion in the case of an update above
You need to use `sql%rowcount`,

TRY:

```
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
  update INVENTORY set OR_Q_TON = 0 ;
END IF;
```

Comment: I tried this but I didn't get (0) ,,, this is an inventory table and the column OR_Q_TON is the sum of the ordered quantity for every item,, but if an item doesn't exist in the orders ,, I want the order quantity to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of using EXCEPTION,

```
IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN 
    UPDATE inventory SET or_q_ton = 0 ;
    COMMIT;
END IF;
```

Comment: The trigger compiles with no errors but I also get (-) instead of (0)

Comment: Might be you have missed something. Can you please post you modified code.

Comment: `create or replace trigger sum_Or_IT
after insert or update or delete on orderitems
begin
    update INVENTORY set OR_Q_TON = (
        select sum(or_quantity_ton) from orderitems 
        where
        orderitems.item_code_orders = INVENTORY.item_code
        and
        warehouse_code = '1');
IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN 
    UPDATE inventory SET or_q_ton = 0 ;
    COMMIT;
END IF;        
end;​`

Comment: Tested your query and was working perfectly. Check your tables orderitems and inventroy whether the data is exists or not with (werehouse_code = '1').

Comment: the warehouse_code =1 in the inventory table but in the orderitems table the whole row doesn't exist so there isn't warehouse_code!

Comment: the field OR_Quantity_Ton is calculated using another trigger should I add this condition to that trigger??

Comment: No need to update that trigger.
Also please check your orderitems.item_code_orders(in your insert query) matches inventory.item_code

Comment: but I need this condition to work when there is no data in the table orders,, for example: when I insert item_code = 4 in the inventory table and there is no Item_code_orders= 4 in the orderitems table.,, The trigger compiles well when the Item_code exists in the table orderitems but it returns (-) when the Item_code doesn't exist in orderitems table.

Comment: From where you get this (-) value?
You mean the sum(or_q_ton)?

Comment: yes the sum(OR_Q_ton) = - and I want it to be 0 because this value will be added to another value

Comment: Can you please share ur sample insert query. So that i can try from here.

Comment: "ORDER_ITEMS_CODE" =1
"ORDER_CODE" =1  
"ITEM_CODE_ORDERS" = 4  
"ORDER_QUANTITY" =2000 
"ORDER_UNIT" = sheet 
"UNIT_PRICE" = calculated using another trigger 
"ORDERED_IN" sheets 
"OR_QUANTITY_TON" = calculated using another trigger
"Warehouse_CODE" =1   this is what I insert in orderitems

Comment: and in Inventory I insert for example  "INVENTORY_CODE" =1 
"ITEM_CODE" =1 
"WAREHOUSE_CODE" =1

Comment: the trigger calculates the "OR_Q_TON" in the inventory table using the trigger, but I inserted ITEM_CODE = 1 and the orders doesn't contain the item which its code is =1 so the "OR_Q_TON" should = 0 because no one ordered this Item, the ordered quantity ("OR_Q_TON") is zero

Comment: If the Item_code I insert in inventory exists in the orderitems table there will be no problem the ordered quantity will be = the sum of the ordered quantities in the table orderitems for the same Item code

Comment: Ok, Then it might be the issue with the trigger you are using to calculate or_quantity_ton. Please check whether the trigger is calculating the or_quantity_ton correctly or not.

Comment: this is the trigger I'm using to calculate the OR_Quantity_ton the trigger took the data from table orderitems and calculate the OR_QUANTITY_TON field which is in inventory table when the item_code in inventory = the item_code in orderitems `create or replace trigger sum_Or_IT
after insert or update or delete on orderitems
begin
    update INVENTORY set OR_Q_TON = (
        select sum(or_quantity_ton) from orderitems 
        where
        orderitems.item_code_orders = INVENTORY.item_code
        and
        warehouse_code = '1');
end;`

Comment: this trigger compiles when the Item_code exists in the orderitems table ,, for example nobody ordered from item no. 4 so in the table orderitems there will not be ITEM_CODE = 4 ,, but the table Inventory will contain all Item_code from 1 to ...n Items and the ordered quantity from Item no.4 will be zero ( OR_Q_TON= 0)

Comment: So I need to add code to this trigger to set the OR_Q_TON = 0 when the ITEM_CODE = 4 for example didn't exist in table orderitems

Comment: Please check the trigger code you have posted to calculate the or_q_ton. I think you have mistakenly pasted the wrong one.

Comment: I finally found the answer ,, I should write (select coalesce(sum(or_quantity_ton),0) from orderitems) instead of (select (sum(or_quantity_ton))) ,, I'm very thankful for your help and concern.

Comment: Ok That's Great.! Anyway if this answer is helpful for you question(Regarding Exception) Please mark it as answered.